# How to get Smart Contract address when it is deployed with web3.js

Tags: node.js, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I have tried to deploy a SmartContract from web3.js node library, I am getting a transaction hash from it but how would I get the contract address after It's been mined by a miner?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that you already have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

finally i got the answer

```
var Tx=require('ethereumjs-tx')
const Web3=require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://rinkeby.infura.io/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

const account1='0xf2b6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx83e9d52d934e5c'
const privateKey1=Buffer.from('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','hex')    


web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1,(err,txCount)=>{
//smart contract data
const data = 'your data here'

//create transaction object
const txObject={
nonce:web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
gasLimit:web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
gasPrice:web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10','gwei')),
data: data
}

//sign the transaction
const tx = new Tx(txObject)
tx.sign(privateKey1)
const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
const raw='0x'+serializedTx.toString('hex')

//broadcast the transaction
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw,(err,txHash)=>{
console.log('err : ',err,'txHash : ',txHash)
//use this hash to find smartcontract on etherscan
}).on('receipt', console.log,);

})
```

.on() method wait till the end of block mining and returns the address of transaction(here contract address). This method is applicable if you don't want to use metamask to sign your transaction and broadcast to the network.

Comment: What if I just want to get the smart contract address by transaction hash which deployed the smart contract?

Comment: Just found one: If you just want to get the smart contract by transaction hash which deployed the smart contract, you can use the the [web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt][1] fetches the receipt for a transaction hash. The receipt has a contactAddress field filled in if the transaction was a deployment.
Check this out: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/3515


  [1]: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt

Answer (score 3):

This returns the contract address...

`MyContract` is the .json file in the `build/contracts` folder that is created by migration.

```
const netId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
const deployedNetwork = MyContract.networks[netId];


const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    MyContract.abi,
    deployedNetwork.address
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `.address` after the object.

```
var contact = web3.eth.contract.new(abi,{from: web3.eth.accounts[0], data: bc});
console.log(contract.address); // Prints address
```

Comment: what is the bc variable?

Comment: This has been changed in latter versions to be `contract.options.address`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the smart contract by transaction hash which deployed the smart contract, you can use the the [web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt) fetches the receipt for a transaction hash. The receipt has a contactAddress field filled in if the transaction was a deployment.
Check this out: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/3515